# Integrating Python Heroku with Firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase, heroku

In a django project I have imported firebase_admin and it worked perfectly on local host, but when I used Heroku to host my web app it gave error no module named 'firbase-admin'. I cross-checked my requirements files and it has firbase-admin. I don't know what's that I did wrong as I made sure that requirements used in virtual environment is same to that in Heroku requirements files.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `firebase-admin==4.3.0` is in your requirements.txt file and try not to generate dependencies manually because you can missout on some libraries preferably use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`